# How do I switch connection string on Linq Entites from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities, sql-server-2012

I have an application written in VB.NET 2012 that connects to a database in SQL Server 2012 using LINQ to Entities.  That works fine.  When I change the connection string to a database with an identical schema on another server with SQL Server 2012 the change works fine too.

My problem is when I point to a third server with a database with the same schema but running SQL Server 2008. I get an error that it doesn't recognize the data object for the first table it tries to query.  I've checked that the tables are named identically.

I've checked that every column matches and both have the same primary Key.

- Is LINQ to Entities from VS2012 fully compatible with SQL Server 2008?
- If it is compatible, is the problem because my EDMX files were created pointing to a database on SQL Server 2012?

The error I get is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.UsewrAccess'.

The table UserAccess is in all three databases.  The two SQL Server 2012 databases work fine.

Comment: `dbo.UsewrAccess` is that a typo?

Comment: **SHOW US** the connection string you're using now! You'll definitely have to change the server/instance name - but other than that, SQL Server 2008 and 2012 should have the same properties and all ....

Comment: This is the connection string as it appears in my app.config file.  I have put ### in place of values I use for data source, id and password for obvious reasons.  When I switch between servere

Comment: String from my app.config: `<add name="UserAccessEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserAccess.csdl|res://*/UserAccess.ssdl|res://*/UserAccess.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=##############;persist security info=True;user id=############;password=##########;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>` 
I do sub values in #s.